# Cобытие в TextBlock?

Tags: wpf

какое  событие срабатывает при изменение текста в TextBlock (WPF) ?

Comment: TextBlock? Никакое, пользователь не может же его править. Просто выполните нужное действие когда правите текст в коде, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Штатного события `TextChanged` у `TextBlock` нет. Это и не удивительно, ведь пользователь не может изменять текст текстблока, логично выполнять нужные действия в коде в тот момент, когда меняете текст явно:

```
myTextBlock.Text = "new text";
SomeMethod(); // Выполняем нужные действия
```

С другой стороны, в WPF можно добавить событие на изменение любого свойства зависимости самостоятельно, поможет нам в этом механизм привязок и прикрепляемых (Attached) свойств и событий. Например, можно написать такой простой класс наблюдателя:

```
public static class Observer
{
    public static object GetBinding(DependencyObject obj)
        => obj.GetValue(BindingProperty);

    public static void SetBinding(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        => obj.SetValue(BindingProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Binding", typeof(object),
            typeof(Observer), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void AddValueChangedHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
        => ((UIElement)d).AddHandler(ValueChangedEvent, handler);

    public static void RemoveValueChangedHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
        => ((UIElement)d).RemoveHandler(ValueChangedEvent, handler);

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ValueChangedEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ValueChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Observer));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        => ((UIElement)d).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ValueChangedEvent, d));
}
```

Всё просто — одно свойство зависимости и одно событие, которое срабатывает при изменении этого свойства. Теперь просто привязываемся к тому свойству, за которым надо следить и добавляем подписчик на новое событие:

```
<TextBlock Name="myTextBlock" Text="111"
           local:Observer.Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
           local:Observer.ValueChanged="myTextBlock_ValueChanged"/>
```

Подписчик:

```
private void myTextBlock_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Текст изменен!");
}
```

Теперь, например, если мы меняем текст при клике по кнопке:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBlock.Text = "222";
}
```

Мы увидим сообщение об его изменении!