# Триггер срабатывающий при изменении свойства на любое значение

Tags: wpf, .net

Подскажите, есть ли возможность установить триггер на изменение свойства на неопределенное или любое значение (Value по сути не нужно)? То есть реагировать на событие изменения свойства.
Задача состоит в том чтобы отследить изменение свойства Source элемента Frame

Comment: Все зависит от того, какие свойства вы применяете. Если обычные, вот такого вида:

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }, то нет.

Если речь идет о свойствах визуальных компонентов, то смотря каких. Большинство из них являются DependencyProperty и, да, изменение таких свойств можно отслеживать.
В чем у вас состоит задача, опишите поподробнее, а то пока вариантов очень много, чтобы их все описывать.

Comment: @АлексейЛосев, спасибо, обновил вопрос

Comment: Вот еще варианты: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/862013/218063 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835910/218063

Answer (score 2):

Для примера создал Frame с именем myFrame:

```
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="myFrame"></Frame>
</Grid>
```

Ну и во так выглядит код форм (вам интересен в первую очередь конструктор, остальное, для показа, что изменение отслеживается:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Frame.SourceProperty, typeof(Frame));
        descriptor.AddValueChanged(myFrame, new EventHandler((sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(((Frame)sender).Source?.ToString())));
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myFrame.Source = new Uri("https://ya.ru");
    }
}
```

Ну и как видно на картинке ниже, после присвоения Source значения, выскочил MessageBox с информацией о присвоенном значении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]